# Can anyone explain what this pageContext.request.contextPath does?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

can anyone explain what will this pageContext.request.contextPath does?it would be helpful if you give an example.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

`${pageContext.request.contextPath}` is an EL expression equivalent to the JSP expression `<%= request.getContextPath() %>`.

It is recommended to use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` instead of hard-coding your context path.

E.g. `<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/info/page.html">Link</a>` is better than `<a href="http://abc.xyz.com/info/page.html">Link</a>`